# Matplotlib use ax.twinx() but only show one set of ticks

Tags: matplotlib

I am trying to plot two dataframes on the same plot using ax.twinx().
the first plots fine:

```py
    figi, ax1=plt.subplots()
    ax1.plot(locals()[edfn].datetime, locals()[edfn].ic_mean, label='ic mean')
    ax2=ax1.twinx()
    ax1.legend(title='gauge name', loc='upper left')
    ax1.set_ylabel('Rain (mm)', rotation=90)
    ax1.set_xlabel('Datetime')
    ax1.tick_params(axis='x',rotation=90)
    #for xx in gl2:
    ax2.plot(locals()[dfn]['datetime'], locals()[dfn][xx]*100, label=xx)
    # mfmt=mds.DateFormatter('%m-%d-%H')
    # ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mfmt)
    # ax1.xaxis.set_(interval=1)
    #ax2.tick_params(axis='x', which='both', bottom=False)
    #ax2.tick_params(labelbottom=False)
    #plt.setp(ax2.get_xticklabels(),visible=False)
    figi.tight_layout()
```

[image]

but when I add the second, which has a nuch finer scale temporal resolution (10 mins as opposed to one hour), it adds every timepoint as a tick on the x axis.

```py
figi, ax1=plt.subplots()
ax1.plot(locals()[edfn].datetime, locals()[edfn].ic_mean, label='ic mean')
ax2=ax1.twinx()
ax1.legend(title='gauge name', loc='upper left')
ax1.set_ylabel('Rain (mm)', rotation=90)
ax1.set_xlabel('Datetime')
ax1.tick_params(axis='x',rotation=90)
#for xx in gl2:
ax2.plot(locals()[dfn]['datetime'], locals()[dfn][xx]*100, label=xx)
# mfmt=mds.DateFormatter('%m-%d-%H')
# ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mfmt)
# ax1.xaxis.set_(interval=1)
#ax2.tick_params(axis='x', which='both', bottom=False)
#ax2.tick_params(labelbottom=False)
#plt.setp(ax2.get_xticklabels(),visible=False)
igi.tight_layout()
```

[image]

As you can see i have tried many different commands , mainly from answers on here, but it just doesn't seem to work!

Comment: What is the dtype of the columns you are using for the x-axis?

Comment: @fdireito aaaaaah, Thankyou... they are type str. I forgot to convert them to datetime when reading from csv :)